# Hyperledger Fabric - Multiple concurrent transactions

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to submit two transactions simultaneously to fabric using the invoke function that I found in the official fabric-samples repository.

If I submit one transaction per time, it is successfully committed to the ledger.

Instead when I try to execute multiple concurrent transactions I get this error:

```
Error: Shutdown due to disconnect on transaction id registration
at ChannelEventHub._callTransactionListener (/Users/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/ChannelEventHub.js:1304:21)
at ChannelEventHub._checkTransactionId (/Users/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/ChannelEventHub.js:1282:9)
at ChannelEventHub._processTxEvents (/Users/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/ChannelEventHub.js:1261:11)
at ClientDuplexStream._stream.on (/Users/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/ChannelEventHub.js:405:11)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at ClientDuplexStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
at ClientDuplexStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
at Object.onReceiveMessage (/Users/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1276:19)
at InterceptingListener.recvMessageWithContext (/Users/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:603:19)
at /Users/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:702:14
```

This is the code snippet that I'm using

```
var invokeChaincode = async function(peerNames, channelName, chaincodeName, fcn, args, username, org_name) {
    logger.debug(util.format('\n============ invoke transaction on channel %s ============\n', channelName));
    var error_message = null;
    var tx_id_string = null;
    try {
        // first setup the client for this org
        var client = await helper.getClientForOrg(org_name, username);
        logger.debug('Successfully got the fabric client for the organization "%s"', org_name);
        var channel = client.getChannel(channelName);
        if(!channel) {
            let message = util.format('Channel %s was not defined in the connection profile', channelName);
            logger.error(message);
            throw new Error(message);
        }
        var tx_id = client.newTransactionID();
        // will need the transaction ID string for the event registration later
        tx_id_string = tx_id.getTransactionID();

        // send proposal to endorser
        var request = {
            targets: peerNames,
            chaincodeId: chaincodeName,
            fcn: fcn,
            args: args,
            chainId: channelName,
            txId: tx_id
        };

        let results = await channel.sendTransactionProposal(request);

        // the returned object has both the endorsement results
        // and the actual proposal, the proposal will be needed
        // later when we send a transaction to the orderer
        var proposalResponses = results[0];
        var proposal = results[1];

        // lets have a look at the responses to see if they are
        // all good, if good they will also include signatures
        // required to be committed
        var all_good = true;
        for (var i in proposalResponses) {
            let one_good = false;
            if (proposalResponses && proposalResponses[i].response &&
                proposalResponses[i].response.status === 200) {
                one_good = true;
                logger.info('invoke chaincode proposal was good');
            } else {
                logger.error('invoke chaincode proposal was bad');
            }
            all_good = all_good & one_good;
        }

        if (all_good) {
            logger.info(util.format(
                'Successfully sent Proposal and received ProposalResponse: Status - %s, message - "%s", metadata - "%s", endorsement signature: %s',
                proposalResponses[0].response.status, proposalResponses[0].response.message,
                proposalResponses[0].response.payload, proposalResponses[0].endorsement.signature));

            // wait for the channel-based event hub to tell us
            // that the commit was good or bad on each peer in our organization
            var promises = [];
            let event_hubs = channel.getChannelEventHubsForOrg();
            event_hubs.forEach((eh) => {
                logger.debug('invokeEventPromise - setting up event');
                let invokeEventPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    let event_timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                        let message = 'REQUEST_TIMEOUT:' + eh.getPeerAddr();
                        logger.error(message);
                        eh.disconnect();
                    }, 3000);
                    eh.registerTxEvent(tx_id_string, (tx, code, block_num) => {
                        logger.info('The chaincode invoke chaincode transaction has been committed on peer %s',eh.getPeerAddr());
                        logger.info('Transaction %s has status of %s in blocl %s', tx, code, block_num);
                        clearTimeout(event_timeout);

                        if (code !== 'VALID') {
                            let message = util.format('The invoke chaincode transaction was invalid, code:%s',code);
                            logger.error(message);
                            reject(new Error(message));
                        } else {
                            let message = 'The invoke chaincode transaction was valid.';
                            logger.info(message);
                            resolve(message);
                        }
                    }, (err) => {
                        clearTimeout(event_timeout);
                        logger.error(err);
                        reject(err);
                    },
                        // the default for 'unregister' is true for transaction listeners
                        // so no real need to set here, however for 'disconnect'
                        // the default is false as most event hubs are long running
                        // in this use case we are using it only once
                        {unregister: true, disconnect: true}
                    );
                    eh.connect();
                });
                promises.push(invokeEventPromise);
            });

            var orderer_request = {
                txId: tx_id,
                proposalResponses: proposalResponses,
                proposal: proposal
            };
            var sendPromise = channel.sendTransaction(orderer_request);
            // put the send to the orderer last so that the events get registered and
            // are ready for the orderering and committing
            promises.push(sendPromise);
            let results = await Promise.all(promises);
            logger.debug(util.format('------->>> R E S P O N S E : %j', results));
            let response = results.pop(); //  orderer results are last in the results
            if (response.status === 'SUCCESS') {
                logger.info('Successfully sent transaction to the orderer.');
            } else {
                error_message = util.format('Failed to order the transaction. Error code: %s',response.status);
                logger.debug(error_message);
            }

            // now see what each of the event hubs reported
            for(let i in results) {
                let event_hub_result = results[i];
                let event_hub = event_hubs[i];
                logger.debug('Event results for event hub :%s',event_hub.getPeerAddr());
                if(typeof event_hub_result === 'string') {
                    logger.debug(event_hub_result);
                } else {
                    if(!error_message) error_message = event_hub_result.toString();
                    logger.debug(event_hub_result.toString());
                }
            }
        } else {
            error_message = util.format('Failed to send Proposal and receive all good ProposalResponse');
            logger.debug(error_message);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error('Failed to invoke due to error: ' + error.stack ? error.stack : error);
        error_message = error.toString();
    }

    if (!error_message) {
        let message = util.format(
            'Successfully invoked the chaincode %s to the channel \'%s\' for transaction ID: %s',
            org_name, channelName, tx_id_string);
        logger.info(message);

        return tx_id_string;
    } else {
        let message = util.format('Failed to invoke chaincode. cause:%s',error_message);
        logger.error(message);
        throw new Error(message);
    }
};
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

```
// the default for 'unregister' is true for transaction listeners
// so no real need to set here, however for 'disconnect'
// the default is false as most event hubs are long running
// in this use case we are using it only once
{unregister: true, disconnect: false}
```

The disconnect option must be set to false, otherwise the connection is shutdown when the transaction is notified to the event.